# SimpleInjector container verify and Akka.net

Tags: simple-injector, akka.net

I'm currently using SimpleInjector together with Akka.net to resolve dependencies that some actors might need from the container. It works well using the [Akka.DI.SimpleInjector](https://github.com/AkkaNetContrib/Akka.DI.SimpleInjector) nuget package.

Now my problem is, that actors, that need some dependencies resolved, have to be registered in the container. Everything is working fine there on that end.

The problem is, that when you call `container.Verify();` that the verification process tries to create the registered actors, which is usually not something you should do outside an `ActorSystem`. So when the container now does that I get an `InvalidOperationException` with a message like `There is no active ActorContext...` and a StackTrace showing that it tries to call the actor constructor.

Anyone any ideas how to solve this problem?

Edit: [Here](https://gist.github.com/thomaslazar/144e4aabfdc6f18dfbd93ca309555597) is an example highlighting the problem. Needs Akka.net and SimpleInjector NuGet.

Edit 2: Updated the gist example to have a fully working program with actors being created and used via DI. The problem with verify still stands.

Comment: Please can you produce a small working example for us to work with?

Comment: Added link to working example into the question.

Comment: Calling `Verify` is strongly recommended, but you don't need to call `Verify` at runtime; see the tip in the docs at https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#verify-configuration, `Verify` can be called during debug wrapped in an `#IF DEBUG` or in a unit test. When you do call `Verify`, don't add the actors to the container. It will do it's job and verify that the configuration for everything else is valid, you'd just have to have a another way via some unit tests of checking that the actors behave correctly when supplied with their dependencies.

Comment: @qujck i *need* the actors registered inside the container. that's the whole point of the thing. the actor system (not in the example) uses the container to resolve the dependencies of said actor.

Comment: @StuartGrassie we register components dynamically by going over assemblies and looking for an interface that when called registers stuff. i have no easy way to *just* not register the actors, because the registration is mixed in with bunch of other things as well. what i would need/like is a way to tell the container "do not check this registration. it's ok. i know what i do. i'm an expert!"

Comment: @ThomasLazar You asked for ideas, I never said it would be easy :)

Comment: @ThomasLazar have you registered the `SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver`?

Comment: @qujck the `SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver` does not get registered in the container. it is used to tie the container to the akka `ActorSystem`. it is of no relevance to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

I wrote this while looking at the example you provided to highlight your problem. That may have mislead me about the *misunderstanding*, I'm going to leave my original reply here as it may help some people.

TL;DR : You can register factories instead of actors and to still have a nice way to express a specific actor dependency you can [use delegates](https://havret.io/akka-net-asp-net-core)

## Original

I think the problem you're having is related to the misunderstanding of two concepts.
Let me ask you two questions :

1. How can we register an object that has to be constructed in a specific way ?
2. What is an actor in Akka.net and how can we interact with it ?

To answer the first question, let's take the `ActorSystem` as an example.
The ActorSystem has to be created through the static method `ActorSystem.Create`.
How can we tell the container how to construct an instance of ActorSystem ?
The answer to that is to use a *Factory*.

We have to register a factory that knows how to construct the ActorSystem. The only responsibility of the factory is to provider an instance of ActorSystem that has been correctly and fully constructed
The factory can be an object but it can also be a function (at least with SimpleInjector).

To fully answer the first question we also have to ask ourselves what would be the object's life-cycle. Is it going to be a singleton ? Can it be constructed each time the dependency is retrieved ?
That solely depends on the dependency type.

If we continue using the ActorSystem as an example, we know it has to be a singleton (well, it's not entirely true, but it is **highly** recommended to have only one AytorSystem in your application and to treat it as a singleton).

With SimpleInjector, we can achieve the above like this :

```
var container = new Container();
container.RegisterSingleton<ActorSystem>(() => ActorSystem.Create("MyActortSystem"));
```

If we apply the usage of a factory to your initial problem, we end up with something like this :

```
var container = new Container();
container.RegisterSingleton<MyActor>(() => Props.Create<MyActor>(() => new MyActor()));
```

The above code doesn't compile because we still have to provide (manually for now) the dependency to the `MyActor` constructor.
**BUT the above code has a second more important issue, it violates a fundamental Akka.net principle : actors should only be access through IActorRef and never directly**

The above code registers the actor with it's type, consumers can then get a reference to an *object* of type `MyActor` instead of the *actor* through `IActorRef`.
The difference is crucial because that's what Akka.net uses to implement the *actor transparency* and also to prevent to misuse the actor.
If you only have an IActorRef, you can only communicate to the actor through `Ask` and `Tell`, you cannot invoke the public methods defined in the MyActor class.
This helps in preventing people from changing/accessing/manipulating the state of the actor from another thread or from outside the actor system.
This is **crucial** for Akka.net or for an Actor based implementation.

I may be insisting, but it's really important to respect the fact that actors should only be accessed through an IActorRef because that's what lets Akka.net keep its promises regarding the Actor model requirements.
Not respecting this can lead to the problems the actor systems try to resolve : thread issues.

That being said, what can we do to solve that issue ?
We know we can register a factory in the container to provide us with an instance of an object that has to be constructed in a specific way.
We cannot register a factory returning a `MyActor` reference because that would violate akka.net requirements. To satisfy those requirements, actors should be accessed through `IActorRef`.
 We could register a factory returning an IActorRef, but that would only work if we only register one actor. We cannot register 2 different factories each returning an IActorRef (different actor).
How would consumers ask for a reference to one actor instead of the other ? We cannot say "give me an IActorRef dependency but only the one that's produced with the second registered factory".
The answer to this problem is, again, *factories*. We have to register a factory that knows how to construct our actor and return it. Consumers should then depend on the factory and not `MyActor`.

Having to create a specific factory to each actor that could be used as a dependency is a bit cumbersome. [Hopefully some people have found an easy way to do it](https://havret.io/akka-net-asp-net-core). We can use *delegates* as a way to model the factory.

The delegate models a *named* factory function. Consumers will then be able to express the dependency on an actor using the corresponding delegate.
Before showing you how it's done, let's examine how it looks like from the consumer :

```
public class Consumer
{
    private IActorRef _myActor;
    public Consumer(MyActor.ReceiveActorProvider myActorFactory)
    {
        _myActor = myActorFactory();
        _myActor.Tell(new SomeMessage());
    }
}
```

The consumer has one dependency `MyActor.ReceiveActorProvider`, it's our delegate, our factory. As it's a factory, it also means it's not our actor, we have to *ask* the factory for our actor, that's what is done thought the invocation of the delegate. In doing that, we end up with an `IActorRef` that is safe to use.

The declaration of the delegate is rather simple :

```
public class MyActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public delegate IActorRef ReceiveActorProvider();
    ...        
}
```

And here's the registration / implementation (I'll walk you through it) :

```
container.RegisterSingleton<MyActor.ReceiveActorProvider>(() =>
{
    var actorSys = container.GetInstance<ActorSystem>();
    var myActor = actorSys.ActorOf<MyActor>(Props.Create<MyActor>(() => new MyActor()));
    return () => myActor;
});
```

First we retrieve, from the container, a reference to the ActorSystem, we then make a new instance of the MyActor though the normal `actorSys.ActorOf` method using the Props.
The *tricky* part is the return. Remember, we are registering a factory or, in other words, "something that returns an IActorRef when invoked", we cannot return `myActor` directly because that would not correspond to the signature of the delegate.
Instead we return `() => myActor` which is a hipster way to say we return a "function that returns myActor".
(The more perceptive among you may have seen that we are, in fact, registering a singleton "factory of factory").

We finally have a way for consumers to ask for a specific actor and giving them a `IActorRef` corresponding to the actor they asked. That takes care of the actor system requirements.

There's still one problem, it still doesn't work, MyActor needs a dependency that is still not resolved ...
There are two answers to that problem :

1. As long as we are *building our [composition root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/)*, we could directly use our `container` in our registrations' functions.
2. The second way is to use Akka.DI.Core, a library that adds support for Dependency Injection to Akka.net. That library only adds the support, it doesn't provide the support for a container. So, in our case, we also have to use the [Akka.DI.SimpleInjector library](https://github.com/AkkaNetContrib/Akka.DI.SimpleInjector).

As this is already quite long, I'm only going to show you how to do the second way :

```
var container = new Container();
var actorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("MyActorSystem");
var resolver = new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container, actorSystem);

container.RegisterInstance(actorSystem);
container.Register<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();
container.RegisterSingleton<MyActor.ReceiveActorProvider>(() =>
{
    var actorSys = container.GetInstance<ActorSystem>();
    var myActor = actorSys.ActorOf(resolver.Create<MyActor>());
    return () => myActor;
});
```

Here we create a `SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver` and use in the actor creation sequence. This object will resolve the dependencies of MyActor when used in `actorSys.ActorOf(resolver.Create<MyActor>())`.
Behind the scene, this object will use Akka.DI.Core to create the Props required by the `ActorOf` method. Akka.DI.Core is also going to use it when the dependencies have to be resolved (Akka.DI.Core is only an abstraction).

## Final words

I took some shortcuts in order to keep it simple (I put the delegates in the Actor class, it's not ideal as it leads consumers to the Actor class when trying to express the dependency and may thus mislead them to use the Actor class directly).
I briefly touched the subject of life-cycle and registered almost everything as singletons. That is not correct, you should ask yourself what is the life-cycle of each of your dependencies and register them accordingly.
I don't claim to be an expert, what I've written here is based on my understanding of IoC, Dependency Injection, and Akka.net, so, I may be wrong (in which case, please let me know so I can improve my understanding).

Comment: I know you put a lot of effort in your answer and your edit. The problem with it is that it goes against how DI should be used with Akka. The documentation is quite specific that you're not supposed to do what you're doing in your answer. https://getakka.net/articles/actors/dependency-injection.html#notes The ActorSystem is the only one doing stuff with actual actor instances and handling their lifecycle.